# Solidity & Web3js: EIP712 signing uint256 works signing uint256[] does not

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm signing orders with [EIP712](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-712.md), and I achieved to recover the data when I sign uint256, as soon as I use uint256[] it recovers to the wrong address.

Can somebody help?

Here is the javascript side of things to create the signature (web3js):

```
var domain = [
  { name: "name", type: "string" },
  { name: "version", type: "string" },
  { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" },
  { name: "salt", type: "bytes32" }
];
var sellOrders = [
  { name: "id", type: "uint256[]" },
  { name: "tokenId", type: "uint256[]" },
  { name: "price", type: "uint256[]" },
  { name: "proto", type: "uint256[]" },
  { name: "purity", type: "uint256[]" },
  { name: "seller", type: "address" }
];
const domainData = {
  name: "app",
  version: "1",
  chainId: 3,
  verifyingContract: cardExchangeContract,
  salt: "0xa222082684812afae4e093416fff16bc218b569abe4db590b6a058e1f2c1cd3e"
};
var message = {
  id: [1],
  tokenId: [1],
  price: [1],
  proto: [1],
  purity: [1],
  seller: address
};
var data = JSON.stringify({
  types: {
      EIP712Domain: domain,
      SellOrders: sellOrders,
  },
  domain: domainData,
  primaryType: "SellOrders",
  message: message
});
window.web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  method: "eth_signTypedData_v4",
  params: [address, data],
  from: address
}, function(error, result) {
  if (error) { 
    errorCallback(); 
  } else {
    const signature = result.result.substring(2);
    const r = "0x" + signature.substring(0, 64);
    const s = "0x" + signature.substring(64, 128);
    const v = parseInt(signature.substring(128, 130), 16);
    successCallback(signature, r, s, v);
  }
});
```

Here is the solidity side of things:

```
string private constant domain = "EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract,bytes32 salt)";
bytes32 public constant domainTypeHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(domain));
string private constant sellOrdersType = "SellOrders(uint256[] id,uint256[] tokenId,uint256[] price,uint256[] proto,uint256[] purity,address seller)";
bytes32 public constant sellOrdersTypeHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(sellOrdersType));
uint256 constant chainId = 3;
bytes32 constant salt = 0xa222082684812afae4e093416fff16bc218b569abe4db590b6a058e1f2c1cd3e;
bytes32 private domainSeparator;

struct SellOrders {
    uint256[] id;
    uint256[] tokenId;
    uint256[] price;
    uint256[] proto;
    uint256[] purity;
    address payable seller;
}

constructor() public {
    domainSeparator = keccak256(abi.encode(
        domainTypeHash,
        keccak256("app"),
        keccak256("1"), // version
        chainId,
        this,
        salt
    ));
}

function recover(uint256[] calldata id, uint256[] calldata tokenId, uint256[] calldata price, uint256[] calldata proto, uint256[] calldata purity, address seller, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external view returns (address) {
    return _recover(id, tokenId, price, proto, purity, seller, v, r, s);
}
function _recover(uint256[] memory id, uint256[] memory tokenId, uint256[] memory price, uint256[] memory proto, uint256[] memory purity, address seller, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) private view returns (address) {
    return ecrecover(hashSellOrders(id, tokenId, price, proto, purity, seller), v, r, s);
}
function hashSellOrders(uint256[] memory id, uint256[] memory tokenId, uint256[] memory price, uint256[] memory proto, uint256[] memory purity, address seller) private view returns (bytes32){
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
       "\x19\x01",
       domainSeparator,
       keccak256(abi.encode(
            sellOrdersTypeHash,
            id,
            tokenId,
            price,
            proto,
            purity,
            seller
        ))
    ));
}
```

When I change the sellOrders attributes to be `uint256` instead of `uint256[]` and provide uint256s instead of arrays it works as expected, and it recovers the correct address. When I set it `uint256[]` and provide arrays it recovers to the wrong address.

**Edit/Added**

The code snippets that actually works, when using uint256 (no arrays):

Javascript (web3js/Metamask):

```
var sellOrders = [
  { name: "id", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "tokenId", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "price", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "proto", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "purity", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "seller", type: "address" }
];

var message = {
  id: 1,
  tokenId: 1,
  price: 1,
  proto: 1,
  purity: 1,
  seller: address
};
```

Solidity:

```
string private constant sellOrdersType = "SellOrders(uint256 id,uint256 tokenId,uint256 price,uint256 proto,uint256 purity,address seller)";

struct SellOrders {
    uint256 id;
    uint256 tokenId;
    uint256 price;
    uint256 proto;
    uint256 purity;
    address payable seller;
}

function recover(uint256 id, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price, uint256 proto, uint256 purity, address seller, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external view returns (address) {
    return _recover(id, tokenId, price, proto, purity, seller, v, r, s);
}
function _recover(uint256 id, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price, uint256 proto, uint256 purity, address seller, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) private view returns (address) {
    return ecrecover(hashSellOrders(id, tokenId, price, proto, purity, seller), v, r, s);
}
function hashSellOrders(uint256 id, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price, uint256 proto, uint256 purity, address seller) private view returns (bytes32){
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
       "\x19\x01",
       domainSeparator,
       keccak256(abi.encode(
            sellOrdersTypeHash,
            id,
            tokenId,
            price,
            proto,
            purity,
            seller
        ))
    ));
}
```

**Added 2**
My last research lead me to https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util/blob/master/index.js#L70-L78 the way Metamask implements the encoding/hashing on the client side, but I was still not able to reproduce this in the solidity contract in order to recover it correctly.

Comment: I think I see the problem but just to be sure can you post both versions of the code(both working and non working)?  Thanks

Comment: Added the code to the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-712.md#definition-of-encodedata:

> The array values are encoded as the `keccak256` hash of the concatenated `encodeData` of their contents (i.e. the encoding of `SomeType[5]` is identical to that of a struct containing five members of type `SomeType`).

So I believe this should work (completely untested):

```
function hashSellOrders(uint256[] memory id, uint256[] memory tokenId, uint256[] memory price, uint256[] memory proto, uint256[] memory purity, address seller) private view returns (bytes32){
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
       "\x19\x01",
       domainSeparator,
       keccak256(abi.encode(
            sellOrdersTypeHash,
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(id)),
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(tokenId)),
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(price)),
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(proto)),
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(purity)),
            seller
        ))
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the chosen answer,

if you have an array of arbitrary sized data you must keccack256 those first i.e. below data is `bytes[]`

```
bytes32[] memory keccakData = new bytes32[](data.length);
for (uint256 i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    keccakData[i] = keccak256(data[i]);
}
```

then you can perform the `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(keccakData))` with the rest of the encoding.

Comment: this was super helpful! this is the only example of this I could find that actually made sense.